# move Android sdk in different partition from ubuntu directory

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, application-development, android, ubuntu-sdk

I am getting complete installation guide at Askubuntu, but i have different problem. **I want to move Android sdk from home directory to a different partition in same hdd**(because I have dual boot win 10+ Ubuntu 16.04 installed and running out of space in Ubuntu). **Is there any way to give path of android sdk(moved in different partition) to android studio?** 
I have tried many time to give the path of different partition where sdk installed but every time it shows sdk setup wizard recursively.
thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to expand the partition size of Ubuntu and shrink the partition size of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I have to resize ubuntu, this was a pain to install it again,this cast me time and resources waste ..I was hoping for a effective solution.